# How to get css to work in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

For some reason my css file isn't doing anything, can anyone help me figure out why? I think it is being sources properly, because when I look in the source code generated when i runserver and click on the link for the css file the text for the css file shows up. Just nothing about the css file is being used

settings.py:

```
import os                                                                        
import sys                                                                                                                                                  

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))                           
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)                                             
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps'))                              

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (                                                               
        os.path.join(DIRNAME, "templates")                                      
)                                                                               

SECRET_KEY = _______                             
DEBUG = True                                                                                                                                                
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True                                                                                                                                       
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []                                                              

# Application definition                                                        

INSTALLED_APPS = (                                                              
        'django.contrib.admin',                                                 
        'django.contrib.auth',   
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',                                          
        'django.contrib.sessions',                                              
        'django.contrib.messages',                                              
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',                                           
        'south',                                                                
        'myapp',                                                                
        'server',                                                               
        )                                                                       

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (                                                          
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',                 
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',                            
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',                            
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',              
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',                 
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',               
         )                                                                       

ROOT_URLCONF = 'server.urls'                                                    

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'server.wsgi.application'                                    


DATABASES = {                                                                   
        'default': {                                                            
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',                             
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),                       
            }                                                                   
        }                                                                       


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'                                                         

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'                                                               

USE_I18N = True                                                                 

USE_L10N = True          
USE_TZ = True                                                                   

STATIC_URL = '/static/'                                                         
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'static')                                   
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DIRNAME, "media")                                     
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url                             
from django.views.static import *                                               
from django.conf import settings                                                
from server import views                                                        

from django.contrib import admin                                                
admin.autodiscover()                                                            

urlpatterns = patterns('',                                                                                          
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='home'),                                       
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),                                  
    url(r'^about/', views.about, name='about'),                                 
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),                           
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT}),

)
```

base.html:

```
{% load server_tags %}                                                          
{% load staticfiles %}                                                          
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                 
<html lang="en">                                                                
<head>                                                                          
<title>{% block page_title %}{{ page_title }}{% endblock %}</title>             
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}server/stylesheet.css" rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>                                                                         
<body>                                                                          
{% nav_bar user %}                                                              
{% block content %}                                                             
{% endblock %}                                                                  
</body>                                                                     
{% include "website/footer.html" %}                                             
</html>
```

stylesheet.css:

```
body {                                                                          
    font-size: 20px;                                                            
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;              
    background-color: blue;                                                     
    text-align: right;                                                          
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
rel="stylsheet"
```

to

```
rel="stylesheet"
```